# Download file after login form with Goutte / Guzzle

Tags: php, file, download, guzzle, goutte

I want to login to a webpage and download a file.

So far I tried the code underneath. The problem is that It seems I'm not authorized anymore. The file downloaded is the login.html page.

Does someone know how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://website.com/login.php');

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'));

...

$download_link = 'https://website.com/extracted_download_link_from_crawler.pdf';

$guzzleClient = $client->getClient();

$response = $guzzleClient->get($download_link, ['save_to' => '/local_path/file.pdf']);
```

Comment: Have you tried to set an user agent?

Answer (score 1):

```
$cookieJar = $client->getCookieJar();
$guzzleClient = $client->getClient();
$jar = GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar::fromArray($cookieJar->all(), 'website.com');
$response = $guzzleClient->get('URL TO FILE', ['cookies' => $jar, 'sink' => 'my.pdf']);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Even if your code solves the OP issue, it is recommended to add some of the descriptive text to your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself:

I get the cookies from the Goutte Client and store them in an Guzzle Client cookiejar:

```
//get the PHPSESSION COOKIE
$cookieJar = $goutteClient->getCookieJar();
$all_cookies = $cookieJar->all();
$PHPSESSID_value = $all_cookies[7]->getValue();

//Update the cookie for different guzzleClient and download
$guzzleClient = $client->getClient();
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
$response = $guzzleClient->get($download_link, ['cookies' => $jar, 'save_to' => '/local_path/file.pdf']);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to read the name of the on the download url? In the above case the name of the file is in the URL. But not always the file name will be provided in the URL.